# How to get values from asynchronous function calls with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I'm just experimenting a bit with the async possibilities in the Spring framework and I'm asking myself how to get an notification when the async function call is done. Is there any callback functionality or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You can have your `@Async` method return a `Future` through which you can obtain return values:

```
@Async
public Future<Something> findSomethingAsync( final int id )
{
    Something s = ...
    return new AsyncResult<Something>( s );
}
```

Once the async method has completed, the `Future`'s `isDone()` method will be true, and you can `future.get()` the result.

Cheers,

Comment: Okay, I knowed that before, but how do I check the value of isDone()? Do I have to implement a loop, which periodically checks it? Or is there any kind of event, which is thrown after completion of the function?

Comment: The `future.get()` will block until a result is available so you don't _have_ to poll...

Comment: Doesn't it miss the target a bit, to call an async function and wait on its completion or which blocks the application? I will try to implement a custom event-based solution.

Comment: Indeed, but there you go... There are some more possibilities using derived classes and Executors, though.